# Rock-Paper-Scissors game tie boolean does not re-initialize within a loop

Tags: java, boolean, flags

I'm working on a rock-paper-scissors program using four methods for a class. Part of the assignment is repeating the game if the user and cpu tie, and ending the game when there is a winner. I've done this by running the whole program through a do-while loop in main() that runs as long as the game is tied (gameTie = true). The issue that I am having is that the value for boolean gameTie only changes after the first game. If the first game is a tie, the program will loop infinitely. If there is a winner, the game ends. I am not sure why the value for boolean gameTie is not being re-initialized after every iteration (meaning after every tie or win). Any advice is appreciated.

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Lab9_2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("This program plays Rock-Paper-Scissors against the computer.\n"
                         + "When there is a tie, the game will restart until a winner is chosen.");
        boolean gameTie = false;
        do {
            int CPUchoice = method1();
                //generate the cpu's play
            
            int userChoiceInt = method2();
                //get the user's play
            
            method3(CPUchoice);
                //output cpu's play
            
            method4(CPUchoice, userChoiceInt);
                //compare both user's play. if they are tied, mark gameTie as true to rerun the loop
                if (CPUchoice == userChoiceInt) {
                    gameTie = true;
                }
            
        }while(gameTie == true);
        
    }
    
    public static int method1() {
        //generate random num 1-3, represents CPU's play
        Random rand = new Random();
        int CPUchoice = rand.nextInt(2);
        return CPUchoice;
    }
    
    public static int method2() {
        //get user's play
        //includes input checking for error prevention
        Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
        boolean uInput; //safe input marker
        char userInputChar; //the character enetered by user for their play
        int userChoiceInt = 0; //the users play, in integer
        
            do { //run user input until user enters a safe input
                System.out.println("\n\nPlease input your choice:");
                userInputChar = kb.next().charAt(0); //get the char input from user
            
                    if(userInputChar == Character.toLowerCase('r')) { 
                        //rock 'r' = 1
                        userChoiceInt = 0;
                        uInput = true;
                    }else if(userInputChar == Character.toLowerCase('p')) { 
                        //paper 'p' = 2
                        userChoiceInt = 1;
                        uInput = true;
                    }else if(userInputChar == Character.toLowerCase('s')) { 
                        //scissors 's' = 3
                        userChoiceInt = 2;
                        uInput = true;
                    }else {
                        //Output error message. mark that user's input is nonsafe
                        System.out.println("Sorry, that's not a valid play. Please try again.");
                        uInput = false;
                    }
            }while (uInput != true);
            
        //return the int value of user's input
        return userChoiceInt; 
    }
    
    public static void method3(int CPUchoice) {
        //output the play made by the cpu in method1()
        String CPUchoiceStr = "";
        if (CPUchoice == 0) {
            CPUchoiceStr = "rock.";
        }
        else if (CPUchoice ==1) {
            CPUchoiceStr = "paper.";
        }
        else if (CPUchoice == 2) {
            CPUchoiceStr = "scissors.";
        }
        System.out.println("The CPU played "+CPUchoiceStr);
    }
    
    public static boolean method4(int CPUchoice, int userChoiceInt) {
        //get CPU choice and user choice
        //calculate and output winnere
        boolean gameTie = false;
            if (CPUchoice == userChoiceInt) {
                //tie
                System.out.println("It's a tie!");
                gameTie = true;
            }
            else if((CPUchoice == 0) && (userChoiceInt == 1)) {
                //cpu = rock user = paper
                System.out.println("Paper covers rock. You win!");
                gameTie = false;
            }
            else if((CPUchoice == 0)&&(userChoiceInt ==2)) {
                //cpu = rock user = scissors
                System.out.println("Rock breaks scissors. You lose.");
                gameTie = false;
            }
            else if((CPUchoice == 1)&&(userChoiceInt == 0)) {
                //cpu = paper user = rock
                System.out.println("Paper covers rock. You lose.");
                gameTie = false;
            }
            else if((CPUchoice == 1)&&(userChoiceInt == 2)) {
                //cpu = paper user = scissors
                System.out.println("Scissors cuts paper. You win!");
                gameTie = false;
            }
            else if((CPUchoice == 2)&&(userChoiceInt==0)) {
                //cpu = scissors user = rock
                System.out.println("Rock breaks scissors. You win!");
                gameTie = false;
            }
            else if((CPUchoice == 2)&&(userChoiceInt ==1)) {
                //cpu = scissors user = paper
                System.out.println("Scissors cuts paper. You lose.");
                gameTie = false;
            }
        return gameTie;
    }
}
```

I have tried initializing the outside variable of boolean gameTie (meaning initializing them outside any loops or if/else statements), also leaving them uninitialized until initialized from a loop condition. I was expecting the boolean gameTie to have an initialized value after every iteration of the game, but instead it is only initializing after the first game. If the first game results in a tie then the program will loop the game infinitely, even if there is a winner (meaning that false should be initialized to gameTie and the do-while loop in main() would not run another time). If the first game has a declared winner, then false should be initialized to gameTie and the program should end (which it does).

Comment: So one thing to focus on is the "minimal" part of "minimal reproducible example" - this is a big chunk of code for us to parse and debug. Before posting, you should pair it down to as small a set as possible as still demonstrates the error. Partially that's for our sake, but it's also just a good debugging technique - when I get stumped, the first thing I'll do is start tearing out functionality to figure out exactly what's broke.

Comment: Doubt this is your problem but `userInputChar == Character.toLowerCase('r')` is backwards - 'r' is already lower case. You want to make their input lower case.

Comment: So long as I'm code reviewing, never name things `method1`, `method2`, etc. You're only going to give yourself and anyone else who reads it a headache. Names should be concise but descriptive.

Comment: So you refer to `gameTie` in two different functions, but it's a local variable in each. Variables are only bound in the block they're defined - so, those two local variables are completely different things and can't see each other.

Comment: Side track a bit. There is no need to use any conditional statements in your entire code to  code this. If-else, switch case & ternary operator are all not necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Your Method4 is returning the gameTie value but you do nothing with it in the Main Method you should say:

```
gameTie = method4(CPUchoice, userChoiceInt);
```